# Is there a good way to deal with different base URLs for local, testing and production?

Tags: php, git, apache, workflow

I was wondering if anyone had a good way of dealing with the situation of having different URL bases for local, testing and production environments.

I try and use relative addresses, but sometimes this isn't possible.

How do I stop things breaking when the homepage of my application changes from:

local:

```
http://localhost:8888/mysite/index.php (URL base is /mysite/)
```

testing:

```
http://mytestingsite.com/testing/mysite/index.php (URL base is/testing/mysite/)
```

production:

```
http://mysite.com/index.php (URL base is /)
```

Comment: The simplest way is to just have the same base everywhere. It's *really* easy to achieve and there is no reason to use anything else. simply `/index.php` would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and a `switch`.

If it matches the given host, define a variable that contains the URL base that you want to use. Have this happen in the header.php, or some settings.php that is always imported, and call this variable when necessary!

Alternatively, have a separate settings.php file in each environment with preset values, but this requires a small change in each codebase.

Answer (score 0):

You should use virtual hosts in the webserver to always have your base URL to be /. See the documentation for your webserver about how to do this.

An other solution is to program your site to allow to be kept in whatever directory. That does probably include prepending all your links with $baseurl that will be calculated in your index.php. However I strongly recommend the first solution.

Comment: Obtaining new domains for every new deployment you make isn't always easy, that's why you often prefer to send your app under a subpath like `maindomain.com/myapp`.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do that.

### Application config

The app's URL base is put in a config file, server side. This is simple to do, but it has the disadvantage that you need to tweak the config every time you deploy your web app under a new URL and you can't reach the same app with multiple URL bases (eg, external proxy-based URL and internal real host URL). As suggested in another answer, the latter can be overcome by configuring a map of `host -> URL-base entries`, where the host is available in the HTTP request headers. However, this still implies some configuration hassle.

### Guess it client side, using Javascript

This is based on the browser property `window.location.href`. For instance, you're in `/index.html` and `window.location.href == http://www.example.com/foo-prefix/index.html`, then you can be reasonably sure that your app was put under `http://www.example.com/foo-prefix/` and all its URLs start from there.

This is quite reliable, though it requires some Javascript coding (I'm not aware of a generic library for doing so, maybe one day I'll publish my own code). Moreover, non-browser clients (eg, curl, wget), might get into trouble due to the fact Javascript isn't executed.

### Guess it server side

This is basically the same approach as the previous one, but it's done server-side, using HTTP request headers. As far as I know, there are ways to get the original client URL in PHP ([example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-the-full-url-in-php/)).

This is more or less the same coding effort you need in Javascript and it might be less reliable (eg, in case the target server sees only requests sent from a proxy or alike).

### A combination of app config and URL guessing

You try to get the app's URL base from a config parameter, if this is null, you resort to the client URL methods above. I use this approach to guess the frontend API: by default, the API is expected to be under `$baseUrl/api`, if it's not there, for instance because someone has deployed the API on another server and another URL, then the only way to find it is via configuration.

### Use HTTP document rewriting

Typically, your app is within an arbitrary URL because it's being mapped by a proxy (eg, Apache reverse proxy). In this case you can use something like the [mod_proxy_html module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html), to rewrite all the documents coming through the proxy and replace all URLs like `/path/to/app/doc` with the URL base (which the proxy knows, for it's the one you're configuring).

The advantage of this is that it's completely transparent to your app, everything is being remapped on the proxy. A disadvantage is you must be in control of the proxy, or have collaborative IT/devop people. Another more serious disadvantage is that likely, this method isn't entirely reliable, cause predicting when a string is a URL in general, is very hard. For instance, suppose some Javascript dynamically compose that URL, finding what's going on is much harder than just seeking for strings. [Example of similar issues](https://serverfault.com/questions/898898/proxyhtmlurlmap-not-modifying-javascript-file).